# Error in Linq Pivot query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When executing the following query using Linq to entities to a "Key/Value Table", I get a `[System.NotSupportedException] "Specified method not supported"`:

Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Pivot = context.goe_postmeta.GroupBy(pm => pm.post_id).Select(
                g => new PivotTemp
                    {
                        ID = g.Key, 
                        FirstName = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_first_name").meta_value, 
                        LastName = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_last_name").meta_value, 
                        Address = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_address_1").meta_value, 
                        PostCode = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_postcode").meta_value, 
                        Phone = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_phone").meta_value, 
                        OrderTotal = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_order_total").meta_value, 
                        PickupLocation = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_pickup_location").meta_value, 
                        PickupTime = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_pickup_time").meta_value, 
                        OrderItems = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_order_items").meta_value
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Pivot = context.goe_postmeta.GroupBy(pm => pm.post_id).Select(
                g => new PivotTemp
                    {
                        ID = g.Key, 
                        FirstName = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_first_name").meta_value, 
                        LastName = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_last_name").meta_value, 
                        Address = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_address_1").meta_value, 
                        PostCode = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_postcode").meta_value, 
                        Phone = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_billing_phone").meta_value, 
                        OrderTotal = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_order_total").meta_value, 
                        PickupLocation = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_pickup_location").meta_value, 
                        PickupTime = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_pickup_time").meta_value, 
                        OrderItems = g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.meta_key == "_order_items").meta_value
                    }).ToList();
```

maybe because you are missing the "." before ToList()?   just a guess

Comment: sorry, it's a typo...the '.' is in place!